# Controlling multiple Digital LED light strip through Servo hat/driver

Tags: led, pwm

After gathering some requirements in my project, I thought that it should be possible for us to control multiple LED Light strip through a servo hat (Considering that we are able to provide enough current to all LEDs through the Servo hat). But from looking at the current Library (https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/tree/master/Adafruit_PWM_Servo_Driver), what can I do to achieve my goal in controlling individual LED on each Light strips on each channel ?

Answer (score 2):

You can not control individually addressable LED strips with PWM.

You need to send a highly precise signal containing RGB values down the strip.

The protocol used is determined by the model of LED strip.

Comment: If OP is trying to use the Servo Hat to increase the number of pins he has to control the LED strips, perhaps a port expander is what is needed?

Comment: I think the OP is trying to control individually addressable LED strips.  They use one of several high speed serial protocols which can not be generated using PWM.  An I2C or SPI port expander would be far too slow for driving such a LED strip.